# Loading screen for using the Stripe API checkout session?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, stripe-payments

I'm using the Stripe API with my web app to create a checkout session but there is an awkward white screen when navigating to the Stripe page for payments.

I'm using NextJS.

When a user clicks on the button:

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router"
const router = useRouter()
...
  <Button
    onClick={() =>
      getCheckoutStripeLink(profile).then((payLink) =>
        router.push(payLink))
    }>
    My billing
  </Button>
...
```

The browser will navigate to `https://billing.stripe.com/p/session/XXX`

In between the user clicking on the button and the browser URL changes to the Stripe URL, there will be a blank white screen.  I can't seem to find a loading hook for the Stripe API that I could use nor do I see a way to do some loading with the NextJS API.

I tried also to have a loading context and set the context to true to get the loading component to render:

```js
...  
  <Button
    onClick={() =>
      getCheckoutStripeLink(profile).then((payLink) => {
        setLoading(true)  // context 
        router.push(payLink)
      })
    }>
    My billing  
  </Button>  
...
```

#### _app.tsx

```js
... 
if (loading || loadingAuth) {  // loading is context  
    console.debug("LOADING on app")
    return <Loading />
}  
...
```

This did not activate the loading screen.

Answer (score 0):

What comes into my mind is to check a state variable in your _app.js file to show a loading screen. It could be something else, but I use user info in this example.

```
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({});

  const getUserInfo = () => {
    let _user = JSON.parse(Account.User.get());

    if (_user) setUserInfo(_user);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUserInfo();
  }, [router.asPath]);

  if (!Object.keys(userInfo).length) {
    return (
      <div id={'globalLoader'}>
        <div className="loader"/>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Here's the css for globalLoader

```
#globalLoader {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1700;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  /*left: 0,*/
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.loader {
  --clr: #3498db;
  /* color of spining  */
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: var(--clr);
}
.loader:before {
  z-index: 100;
  animation: spin 1s infinite;
}
.loader:after {
  border: 10px solid #ccc;
}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've examined your code. I have another suggestion.

When user clicks the button, we set the redux reducer variable (loading) and then we control it on the directed page instead of _app.js.

```
  <Button
    onClick={() =>
      getCheckoutStripeLink(profile).then((payLink) => {
        dispatch(setLoading(true));  // context 
        router.push(payLink)
      })
    }>
    My billing  
  </Button>
```

```
const PayLink = () => {
    const loading: boolean = useAppSelector(
        (state) => state.commonSlice.loading
    );

    useEffect(() => {dispatch(setLoading(false))}, [])

    if (loading) {
        return (
            <div id={'globalLoader'}>
                <div className="loader"/>
            </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <>
          // ..
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: I already have a hook for the authentication loads.  The authentication state is not the object that loads when navigating to another site.

Comment: I did get an idea from your answer and used the loading as a context.  Then I `setLoading(true)` when the user would navigate to an external site but this did not activate the loading screen.

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: I added to the original question.  See "I tried also to have a loading context and set the context to true to get the loading component..."

Comment: Okay, I have an update